# Фоновое изображение во фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Как сделать фоновое изображение в фрагменте Android? Желательно, полупрозрачное.

Upd.

Сделал с android:alpha=".5" - стало всё прозрачное, вместе с другими элементами. 
Так как сделать, таким же прозрачным только фон, не трогая другие элементы?

Comment: android:alpha=".5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. За фон отвечает аттрибут `android:background`
2. Чтобы назначить фон только основному элементу разметки фрагмента надо именно так и сделать. Взять его разметку и присвоить ей фон используя аттрибут из п.1.
3. Чтобы фон был полупрорачный можно (в случае если фон - цвет) добавить `88` перед значением цвета. (т.е. `#88424242` вместо `#424242`). Если фон - картинка, то надо получить корневой элемент разметки в `onCreateView` фрагмента, получить его фон методом `getBackground()` и присвоить ему прозрачность методом `setAlpha(125)`

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ИМЯ_ФАЙЛА_РАЗМЕТКИ, container, false);
       v.getBackground().setAlpha(125);
       ...
       return v;
   }
   ```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @ЛевНауменко, пожалуйста)